# Notice: Undefined property: stdClass error on front end

Tags: php, joomla, xampp, undefined-reference, stdclass

I can't figure out how to make this line defined. If anyone can offer assiatnce that would be appreciated, probably something very simple.

This line: $value = $value->published;

Keeps giving me this error - Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$published

```
public static function published($value, $i, $img1 = 'tick.png', $img0 = 'publish_x.png', $prefix = '')
{var_dump($value); die();
    if (is_object($value))
    {
        $value = $value->published;
    }

    $img = $value ? $img1 : $img0;
    $task = $value ? 'unpublish' : 'publish';
    $alt = $value ? JText::_('JPUBLISHED') : JText::_('JUNPUBLISHED');
    $action = $value ? JText::_('JLIB_HTML_UNPUBLISH_ITEM') : JText::_('JLIB_HTML_PUBLISH_ITEM');

    $href = '
    <a href="#" onclick="return listItemTask(\'cb' . $i . '\',\'' . $prefix . $task . '\')" title="' . $action . '">'
        . JHtml::_('image', 'admin/' . $img, $alt, null, true) . '</a>';

    return $href;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

These lines don't make much sense:

```
$value = new stdClass();
$value = $value->published; // attempt to read from an undefined property
```

You're creating a clean object with no properties, then trying to read from one - hence the error. What are these lines meant to do?

If I had to make a stab in the dark, try removing `$value = new stdClass();` and see if that now works. I imagine you want the first parameter of your `published()` function to accept either a boolean or object.

Comment: Okay, I deleted the "$value - new stdClass();" line and I am still getting this error message:

Comment: Here's the new code: if (is_object($value))
  {
   $value = $value->published;
  }

Comment: The error message didn't come through. Can you put `var_dump($value); die();` at the top of your function and add the output to your question?

Comment: Still getting this error message: "Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$published"

Comment: You need to add the code in my last comment inside the method body - i.e. after `{` on the line before `if (is_object($value))`.

Comment: Okay I made the changes and reflected them above. After applying this and reloading the page, the page loaded in only text characters with no graphic designs and looks very funky so I took that line out, it's still in my code above so you can see.

Comment: It wouldn't look pretty - it's printing out `$value`. Unfortunately I need that funky output to help you further. If you don't want to add it to your question, put it on Pastebin.

Comment: You need to give some more context.  If you do var_dump($value) does the published property exist?  If you are in joomla most likely you are one of the horrible is it published or is it state situations, so try also saying $value->state.   Is value a row of data from your joomla database?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `property_exists()` PHP function or use `isset($value->published)`:

```
public static function published($value, $i, $img1 = 'tick.png', $img0 = 'publish_x.png', $prefix = '')
{
    if (is_object($value) && property_exists($value,'published'))
    {
        $val = $value->published;
        if(isset($val)) 
        {
            $img = $val ? $img1 : $img0;
            $task = $val ? 'unpublish' : 'publish';
            $alt = $val ? JText::_('JPUBLISHED') : JText::_('JUNPUBLISHED');
            $action = $val ? JText::_('JLIB_HTML_UNPUBLISH_ITEM') : JText::_('JLIB_HTML_PUBLISH_ITEM');

            $href = '<a href="#" onclick="return listItemTask(\'cb' . $i . '\',\'' . $prefix . $task . '\')" title="' . $action . '">'
    . JHtml::_('image', 'admin/' . $img, $alt, null, true) . '</a>';

            return $href;
        }
    }
    else {
        var_dump($value);
        die();
    }
}
```

Also I would change the variable name to `$val` when comparing so that the referenced variable is not modified in any way by the function.